# leaks детектит утечку памяти в дочернем процессе на mac os

Tags: c, утечка-памяти, fork

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "libft/libft.h"

int main()
{
    pid_t pid;

    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
    {
        getchar(); 
    }
    else
    {
        waitpid(-1, 0, WUNTRACED);
        getchar();
    }
    
}
```

Вроде накосячить тут было бы сложно. Не понимаю что именно течет и как это пофиксить

Comment: здесь как то очень много include. Я бы для начала поисключал их по максимуму.

Comment: к сожалению это не работает(

Comment: а то такое leaks, что оно умеет такое? это какая то утилита с макоси?

Comment: leaks аналог valgrind, если можно так выразиться на линуксе, ищет утечки памяти наверное может и еще что то

Comment: возможно потому, что Вы запускаете его без параметра "отслеживать порожденные процессы"